# How to set a 'plain' exception handler in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In `Laravel 4.1` a plain exception is shown when an exception in thrown and debug is set to `false`.

The message is along the lines of:

> Whoops, something has gone wrong

I've trawled through the code, and it seems that the plain exception handler is registered in:

```
Illuminate\Exception\ExceptionServiceProvider.php
```

via the following line

```
protected function registerHandler()
{
    $this->app['exception'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
    {
        return new Handler($app, $app['exception.plain'], $app['exception.debug']);
    });
}
```

Where do I set my own custom plain handler? I don't like the "Whoops" message, I want to be able to show a site specific message

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the plain exception handler;, already available in `app/start/global.php` by default, modify it as given below (Btw, [Whoops! PHP Errors only for Cool Kids](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/whoops-php-errors-for-cool-kids--net-32344)):

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);Log::error($exception->getMessage());
    return View::make('errors.index')->with('exception', $exception);
});
```

Create a view `view/errors/index.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Oops!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class='well'>ERROR: {{ $exception->getMessage() }}</div>

@stop
```

Also make `'debug' => false` in your `app/config/app.php` file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Debug Mode
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
| stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
| application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
|
*/

'debug' => false,
```

You have following methods to use in `$exception` object:

```
array (size=10)
  //0 => string '__construct' (length=11)
  1 => string 'getSeverity' (length=11)
  2 => string 'getMessage' (length=10)
  3 => string 'getCode' (length=7)
  4 => string 'getFile' (length=7)
  5 => string 'getLine' (length=7)
  6 => string 'getTrace' (length=8)
  7 => string 'getPrevious' (length=11)
  8 => string 'getTraceAsString' (length=16)
  //9 => string '__toString' (length=10)
```

If you leave `'debug' => true,` then still your exception handler will work but in  some cases it may display `whoops` when the exception is not caught in you handler but in another specific handler before your generic `Exception` handler.

Also remember that, `Exception` class is the most generic exception type, if you have other more specific exception handlers defined after that then it'll not get triggered if any response returned from that specific handler.

Comment: Man almost too easy, not to take away from the answer though. Thanks @WereWolf - The Alpha

Answer (score 1):

In your app/start/global.php file add

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return 'Your custom message'; // you can also specify a view to render.
});
```

Please visit http://laravel.com/docs/errors for more information

Comment: That only handles 404's I believe. I'm looking to catch all the other exceptions. Normally caught at App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
 Log::error($exception);
});